# Python How to make a proper string slicing?

Tags: python, string, slice

I can't figure out how to properly slice a string.
There is a line: "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6". The number of characters is unknown, numbers can be either one-digit or three-digit
I need to get the last value up to the nearest comma, that means I need to get the value (6) from the string

Comment: You can get the position of the last comma in the string using `rindex`, and then make a slice starting from that position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to split and get last value

```py
string = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6"
string.split(',')[-1]
>>> ' 6'
```

add strip to get rid of the white spaces

```
string.split(',')[-1].strip(' ')
>>> '6'
```

Answer (score 2):

Better use [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit), setting `maxsplit=1` to avoid unnecessarily splitting more than once:

```
string = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6"
last = string.rsplit(', ', 1)[-1]
```

Output: `'6'`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me the easiest way would be to use the method `split` and divide your string based on the comma.

In your example:

```
string = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6'
last_value = string.split(', ')[-1]
print(last_value)

Out[3]: '6'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that should do it for you:

```
def get_last_number(s):
    return s.split(',')[-1].strip()
```

Trying it on a few test strings:

```
s1 = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6"
s2 = "123, 4, 785, 12"
s3 = "1, 2, 789654 "
```

...we get:

```
print (get_last_number(s1))
# 6
print (get_last_number(s2))
# 12
print (get_last_number(s3))
# 789654
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to split the string:

```
string = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6'
splitted_str = string.split(',')
```

Then, you should get the last element:

```
last_elem = splitted_str[-1]
```

Finally, you have to delete the unnecessary white spaces:

```
last_number_str = last_elem.strip()
```

Clearly this answer is a string type, if you need the numeric value you can cast the type by using

```
last_elem_int = int(last_elem_str)
```

Hope that helps